# Eclipse java libraries

Tags: java, eclipse, git

I'm kind of new to Eclipse and I'm hating it so far
The question is I'm working on a small project with some classmates, we are using Eclipse and Git but every time someone does an immport all the libraries are lost because they are referencing the computers path like C:/someone/something.jar and then someone else push something to github and the libraries path C:/someone2/somthing.jar

Every time, I and my partners have to search for the libraries on our pc so the errors stop appearing.

Is there an easier way so we don't have to lose time searching for the libraries on our pc?

Comment: Add the `.classpath` to git-ignore. Use maven, and rebuild the classpath, add the jars to the project and use relative paths in the classpath.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need Java build tool like [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/), [Gradle](http://www.gradle.org/) to manage your dependencies.

In that way, it will resolve the libraries for you. And in the source code, you should not check in `.classpath`,`.project` meta files. Those files should be added into `.gitignore` to avoid commit.

To import projects into IDE (Eclipse in your case), Maven and Gradle can help you to generate those IDE meta files. Or some Eclipse plugins could be used to import maven or gradle project.

Answer (score -1):

You should create a folder for libraries and put all jar files in there, add these files to classpath using Java Build Path Option from project properties. Also add this folder to git